# Django DRF: Restricting PUT options in ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to restrict my ViewSet so that it allows for different inputs based on permissions:

My models:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    page = models.PositiveIntegerField("page", default = 1, choices = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)])
    layouts = models.ManyToManyField(Layout)

class Layout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 32)
```

Serializer:

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_layouts")

    def get_layouts(self): ## this is not displayed?
        return "test" 

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ["name", "page", "test"]
```

I have a helper class that provides a `all_pages` permission for example. in the restframework API I now have a dropdown from page 1-3, but if the user does not have the right to use all pages, I want to only show `page 1` for selection (or make it a text field witout input field).
Same problem applies for the `ManyToMany` field: How can I restrict the layouts dropdown options to the ones I selected in the admin-planel for that user?

Right now I manually check everything in the `PUT` method of the `ViewSet` and return a "user is not allowed ... -> BAD REQUEST".

EDIT: BC I was asked, right now I do something like this:

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'head']
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication,]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    def list(self, request):
    ...

    def put(self, request):
        ## page logic
        if "app.all_pages" in request.user.get_user_permissions():
            try:
                if not 1 < int(request.data["page"]) <= 3:
                    return Response(data = "page not 2 or 3", 
                                    status = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
            except Exception as E:
                return Response(data = f"""Error in page selection: {E}""", 
                                status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            page = int(request.data["page"])
        else:
            page = 2
        
        ## layout logic:
        store = Store.objects.get(user = request.user)
        allowed_layouts = [l.id for l in store.layouts.all()]
        if not int(request.data["layout"]) in allowed_layouts:
            return Response(data = f"""layout not allowed for store {store}""", 
                            status = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        layout = Layout.objects.get(pk = request.data["layout"])
        
        ## do something with page 2 and layout ... in DB/another API
```

Comment: Post your viewset/s related to the logic. post your helper methods too

Comment: I updated my question by my workaround (this works well, but I am sure it is a pretty sub-optimal solution).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, so I'm going to explain how permissions work and you'll use them yourself.

**P.1**

Permissions in DRF as just wrappers for 2 methods, here's how it works.

```
class PermissionX:
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)
        return True
```

This is a permission, `has_permission` says (`request.user` has permission to access the
current `view`?) and `has_object_permission` says (`request.user` has persmission to act on `obj`).

The `obj` is the object being acted on inside the view. If your view works with users, the object will be an instance of `User`.

This is used with `permission_classes` like this

```
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, PermissionX]
```

**P.2**

You usually use `user.has_perm(perm)` instead of `'name' in user.permissions`. This is because the permissions can exist in `user.groups` and not only `user.permissions`.

**P.3**

Any exception raised should be of type `PermissionDenied` which exists in DRF.

**P.4**

Extract your permission in a permission.py folder in your current app.

**P.5**

Your permissions won't be integrated in django admin's interface. This is because it's not using DRF and it's not using your endpoints. It's using things that django made available for it. This is normal, the logic we're talking about will be enforced by your API itself and when you create a custom dashboard, you need to enforce it on the frontend as a type of UX as well.

Comment: First: Thanks for your detailed answer. Appreciated! But it does not contain a very major point of my question: If for example a User (A) is logged in and sees the dropdown from page 1 - 3, how can I make a user (B) (who does not have to permission to see all pages) present a menu with only one (page 1) entry when he loggs in? Or do I think wrong about all that and it is all about "show everything and raise exception if perm denied"?

Comment: Page itself maybe be a model that has permissions

Comment: Yes, this is how I did it so far. I was just thinking that maybe it could be better to "hide" fields/options a user cannot access anyways.

Comment: Yep, it's better, by creating a dynamic serializer for this (documented)

Comment: this is exactly what my question was aiming at. Could you show how to approach the "page" case I had in my original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230957/discussion-between-ahmed-i-elsayed-and-xtlc).