# DRF - filtering / customizing options in PUT request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I already tried to find some answers ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020815/django-drf-restricting-put-options-in-viewset)) - with very little success.
I want to filter the items the DRF api page returns in the PUT options:

lets assume a simple model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = '')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Price(models.Model):
    amt = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

so every product is linked to a user in the following way:

```
Product |  User
----------------
four    |  user2
three   |  user1
two     |  admin
one     |  admin
```

If I now define a `ViewSet`:

```
class PriceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'head']

    def get_queryset(self):
        prods = Product.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
        return Price.objects.filter(product__in = prods)
    
    def list(self, request):
        results = PriceSerializer(data = self.get_queryset(), many = True)
        results.is_valid()
        return Response(data = results.data)

    def put(self, request):
        prod = Product.objects.get(id = request.data["product"])
        price = Price.objects.get(product = prod)
        price.amt = request.data["amt"]
        price.save()
        return Response(data = "OK")
```

I see the following result (logged in as admin):

[image]

Why is the user able to even see product three & four (not owned by admin, not in the `get_queryset`)? How can I filter them for the `PUT` dropdown?

PriceSerializer for completeness sake:

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ["amt", "product",]
```

Comment: the answer you find is true. you need to use permissions. This people can only reach the items that they have permission which you can define it as ownership.

Comment: yes, I know I can check for `user` in `put` method and easily and just don't do the saving. But I don't want user1 to see user2 products by viewing the api.

Comment: This really is a non-issue. The API browser is for quick & dirty request testing, sort of a poor-man's Postman. Don't waste your time trying to filter options. Either implement it as part of the API (and the API browser will follow suit) or just accept its behaviour.